# How to find distinct indices of elements of one unsorted array in another one?

Tags: c++, arrays, time-complexity

There are 2 character arrays. Both the arrays are of same size and jumbled forms of each other.

For example:

```
char a[] = {'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c' };
char b[] = {'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a' };
```

I want to find the distinct positions(1-based indexing) of elements of array *b* in array *a*, which is: 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 10, 7, 9, 6, 8, for this example.

I implemented the following brute-force approach which is *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (b[i] == a[j])
        {
            cout << j + 1 << " ";
            a[j] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any approach in C++ by which this time complexity can be reduced to something like *O*(*n* * log(*n*)) or even less?

Comment: Will the arrays only contain a, b, or c?

Comment: I don't understand how you came up with answer given the values of the elements of `a` and `b`.

Comment: You can have a map kind of `int char_map[256]={0}; char_map[symbol]++;`. It will give some time gain in cost of memory.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah The arrays consist of any combinations of a-z (only lowercase), no numbers/special characters/spaces.

Comment: @RSahu 1st element in b[ ] is 1st element in a[ ], 2nd element in b[ ] is 3rd element in a[ ] (Since I have considered one 'a' of arrays a[ ] & b[ ] already, so, I have changed that 'a' of a[ ] to '\0'). The reason is that both these arrays are jumbled forms of each other.

Comment: @Olia_Pavliuk Can you please explain your method in some more detailed way ?

Comment: @dashthird -- Indices in C++ start at 0, not 1.  Why doesn't your output reflect this, at least to not confuse things?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry if my question confused you. But I have used j+1 in the output statement to show positions in terms of 1-based indexing.

Comment: @dashthird I meant something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/48653463/2567725

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply insert the indices into a multimap keyed by the value of the element, then iterate the other array, find the first index which is what you need, then erase it from the map. Should be O(n log n):

```
std::multimap<char, int> charmap;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof a; i++) {
    charmap.emplace(a[i], i);
}


for (char c : b) {
    auto it = charmap.find(c);
    std::cout << it->second + 1 << " ";
    charmap.erase(it);
}
```

Comment: For large datasets, `unordered_multimap` should be faster, even for a single instance of the 2nd loop.  By large, I mean at least in the thousands.

Comment: @zzxyz unlike `multimap` however, `unordered_multimap` doesn't maintain the insertion order of elements, so it would result in *some* possible "jumbling" of indices, but not necessarily *the* one jumbling where first element of `b` was jumbled to the first of the indices in `a` where the element is equal.

Comment: ah, didn't occur to me.  One would *think* only indexes would be jumbled rather than the values associated with them.  Otherwise my answer starts to look pretty good for large datasets.  It's kind of an odd, fun, problem that I'm surprised I haven't run into before.

Answer (score 2):

It can be reduced to the O(n) time at cost of O(n) memory.

You should create two dimensional array. Its first dimension will be by all characters (total 256=2^8 indices, because sizeof(char)=1 byte), the second dimension will be over n elements of you array.

So, if you have

```
char a[n] = ...;
char b[n] = ...;
```

You should allocate

```
int c[256][n]; // O(n) memory
int s[256]; // O(1) memory
int e[256]; // O(1) memory
```

and fill them by zeros. You will be able to use e[i] as counter for number of characters with code **i** in **a**. In c[i][0], c[i][1], ... you can store actual positions of characters witch code **i** in array **a**.

First step is to iterate over array **a** and each time

1. write position of character into c[a[i]][m] = i, where m = e[a[i]]
2. increase e[a[i]]

You can use array **s** to store number of already printed positions of symbols (s[j] is number of printed characters with code **j**). Second step is to iterate over **b** and each time

1. output c[b[i]][m], where m = s[b[i]]
2. increase s[b[i]]

Each step consumes O(n) time, so total time complexity is O(n). It is important to note, that this complexity is not **mean** case with use of randomized approaches (like hash table where you must think about probability of hit). This complexity will be the same in the **worst** scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a hash table, and in each bucket, there is a list. The list will contain the indices of b[], at which the character occurs.

Take each element in b[], say b[i], find the list in the hash table with index equal to b[i] (which will be 'a' or 'b' or 'c' in your case). If there is no list, create a list with value i+1. If a list is found add i+1 to the end of the list

In your example, after your insertion is done

- 'a' will be list 1,2,9,10
- 'b' will be list 3,4,7,8
- 'c' will be list 5,6

As and when you process an entry, you use the 1st element in the list and remove the first element from the list. 
 In the above example,

After processing the 1st entry 'a' - you will give 1, and remove 1 from list at index 'a'. Now

- 'a' will be list 2,9,10
- 'b' will be list 3,4,7,8
- 'c' will be list 5,6

After processing 2nd entry 'b' - you will give 3 and remove 3 from from list at index 'b'. Now

- 'a' will be list 2,9,10
- 'b' will be list 4,7,8
- 'c' will be list 5,6

This would be O(N)? (assuming you have doubly linked list)

Comment: Are you saying that complexity=O(n) if A & B are doubly linked lists instead of arrays ?

Comment: No. I am saying hash table insert is O(1). To add N entries from array A  to a hash table it will be O(N). We are maintaining a list at every index. I just mentioned that list is a doubly linked list - so we can add to end and remove the head in O(1).

Comment: As I am a beginner, can you suggest some online resources to study STL hash table implementations? (I have upvoted your answer, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** 
I prefer the answer of @user2079303 to mine.  Same concept, easier implementation.

Concrete implementation of a reverse lookup.  You'll see that the first two loops are overhead.  `unordered_map` is basically the "hash table" suggested in the other answer.

`auto it` is an iterator where `first` is the index and `second` is the value (a `queue`, in our case).  What makes this confusing is that being a reverse lookup, the "index" is also what you consider the values (and vice-versa with each "value" on the queue being an index into `a`.

I used a queue because you only want to use each index once (so the `pop` is your equivalent to setting the value to `\0`).

I think the best way to understand it is to step through it in a debugger, though.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char a[] = { 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c' };
  char b[] = { 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a' };
  unordered_map<char, shared_ptr<queue<int>>> reverseIndex;
  //create a queue for each unique char
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    auto it = reverseIndex.find(a[i]);
    if (it == reverseIndex.end())
    {
      reverseIndex.emplace(a[i], make_shared<queue<int>>());
    }
  }
  //put the indexes as *values* into our unordered_map vectors
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    auto it = reverseIndex.find(a[i]);
    it->second->push(i);
  }

  //perform the actual work
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    auto it = reverseIndex.find(b[i]);
    cout << it->second->front()+1 << "\n";
  //you'll need to push the value back onto the queue for multiple uses of reverseIndex:  it->second->push(it->second->front());
    it->second->pop();
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the time complexity of your approach?

Comment: O(n).  The overhead of setting up the reverse index (which only needs to be done once), is about O(2n).  (You could combine the loops, but I wanted what was happening to be clear, and it wouldn't matter much anyway.)

Comment: @dashthird - unordered_map::find does get slower with larger data sets, but not by much.  I've used it to index a set of 30 million, and it's effectively instant.